# Unable to convert file from ANSI to UTF-8, using PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a file, which contains some cyrillic characters. When I open this file in Notepad++ I see, that it has ANSI encoding. If I manually encode it into UTF-8 using Notepad++, then everything is absolutely ok - I can use this file in my parsers and get results. But what I want is to do it programmatically, using PHP. This is what I tried after searching through SO and documentation:

```
file_put_contents($file, utf8_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
```

In this case when my algorithm parses the resulting files, it meets such letters as "è", "í" , "â". In other words, in this case I get some rubbish. I also tried this:

```
file_put_contents($file, iconv('WINDOWS-1252', 'UTF-8', file_get_contents($file)));
```

But it produces the very same rubbish. So, I really wonder how can I achive programmatically what Notepad++ does. Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you run your file's contents through `mb_detect_encoding($contents, 'auto', true)`?

Comment: @Graham. Just a second. I will check it

Comment: It seems like I get an empty string. Probably, mb_detect_encoding does not detect anything

Comment: BTW. Should I do it before or after any conversion? I tried to do it before conversion

Comment: OK. Well afaik Windows-1252 is Latin, so I imagine your contents are actually Windows-1251; try that in iconv instead.

Comment: It works! It would be great, if you could make an answer with an explanation from you comment. It would be helpful for many people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notepad++ may report your encoding as ANSI but this does not necessarily equate to Windows-1252. 1252 is an encoding for the Latin alphabet, whereas 1251 is designed to encode Cyrillic script. So use

```
file_put_contents($file, iconv('WINDOWS-1251', 'UTF-8', file_get_contents($file)));
```

to convert from 1251 to utf-8 with iconv.